# i have a 2002 e-320 the abs light and bas/esp light came on, it caused reduced power and when i shut it off, it will not crank. any ideas

Tags: starting, troubleshooting

the abs light and bas/esp. light came on while driving had reduced power when running I shut it off and now no start and no crank. any ideas please?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I’m assuming that by the ABS light you mean the AntiLock Braking system light. I don’t understand what a bas / esp light is. Are you able to read stored maintenance codes from the OBD2 (OnBoard Diagnostics) port?

Comment: @zipzit abs, bas & esp are all part of the braking system. Add limp home and no start; first suspect could just be battery. Battery age would be useful info (can add proper answer when I get back to compy, can't type properly with my thumbs;)

Comment: @Tetsujin  I guess that was too subtle. Am I the only person highly offended by the use of mystery unexplained abbreviations?  Best practice is to full define ALL abbreviations When First Used (WFU) style. Good communication is free. With that said what do the abbreviations BAS and ESP stand for?

Comment: There's one old GM car model known to trigger its abs light but was never found to be an abs issue. The abs indicator was "the canary in the mine" alerting the owners (repeated several times with this model) to main power issues. Main power; battery, battery cables and their connections, main grounds, serpentine drive belt, belt tensioner and lastly the alternator. Did you examine everything related to electrical power?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the antilock brake system light came on then brake assist system/electronic stability light came on lost power was able to limp back. now will not crank, no codes